# Angular-datatables Bootstrap search bar CSS

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-datatables

I'm using **angular-datatables** with the Bootstrap integration. However, the search bar looks weird. It doesn't look like the normal Bootstrap text fields with that nice glow effect.

This is the angular-datatables search bar:

[image]

This is the Jquery Datatables search bar:

[image]

And I'm not doing anything wrong because the demo on the angular-datatables site looks the same: https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/bootstrapIntegration

Does anyone know how I can have the regular Bootstrap look in angular-datatables? Maybe some CSS code for me to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular dataTables overrides the bootstrap css, with this css class `.dataTables_filter input[type="search"]` so if you want to regain the bootstrap css you should remove this class from the angular-datatables.css file.

If you don't want to edit the dataTables css you can add this:

```
.dataTables_filter input[type="search"]:focus {
    border-color: #66afe9;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075),0 0 8px rgba(102,175,233,.6);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075),0 0 8px rgba(102,175,233,.6);
}
```

to your css file put it after both the angular datatables and bootstrap css.

Comment: Thank you! I just tried that and it works! However, I really don't want to be changing the default .css files and instead do my own changes in a separate .css file. Do you have a way to do that?

Comment: @T.Ferreira  Updated my answer,

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much! :)